# LINQ query with GROUP, JOIN, SUM + CASE referring other than grouped table

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have been given some SQL statements as source for statistics charts and the last one is giving me problems when I try to translate that to LINQ (query). I have seen several similar questions posted but the problem for me here is that the CASE and SUM isn't on the grouped table but on another one joined in. How to get working LINQ from the supplied SQL?

This is the SQL I have been given:

```sql
select a.Name,sum(case when rp.TypeId in (1,3) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Information', sum(case when rp.TypeId in (2,4) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Maintenance' from POAs p 
join ReceivedPOAs rp on (p.id=rp.id)
join Agents a on (rp.AgentId=a.Id)
where ISNULL(p.InsertedInUpdateDatabaseMode,'N')='N'
group by a.Name
order by count(*) desc
```

...and when run it results in:

```
Name            Information Maintenance
Broker1         133         35
Insurer2        99          37
Insurer1        92          2
Broker2         53          15
Test AB         33          3
Our Partners    6           1
Your AB         1           1
Last One        1           0
```

The problem I have is with those

```
sum(case when rp.TypeId in (1,3) then 1 else 0 end)
```

...since they are referring to "rp" and not to "a" which is group on (all examples I have found have had the sum done on something in the group)

I started writing code on the same format as I have in my previous, working, translations, however soon realized that I don't know where to have the addition in my code...

```cs
            var query = p in POAs.Where(x => x.InsertedInUpdateDatabaseMode == null || x.InsertedInUpdateDatabaseMode == "N")
                        join rp in ReceivedPOAs on p.Id equals rp.Id
                        join a in Agents on rp.AgentId equals a.Id
                        group a by a.Name into ag
                        orderby ag.Count() descending
                        select new StatReportDataItems
                        {
                            Label = ag.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                            NumData1 = (double)
                            (
                                rp.TypeId == 1 || rp.TypeId == 3 ? 1 : 0
                            )
                        };
            return query.ToList();
```

It's quite fine by me if someone would want to change the SQL code to a version better translatable to a LINQ query. I'm also OK with changing the LINQ query to two or more parts, if it just works :-)

Getting a solution in pure method syntax is also OK, but since the other LINQ queries in the program are written in query format I would prefer that.

So, the result of the call would be a list of StatReportDataItems. This is used for all chart routines, hence NumData1 is of type double instead of int as would be natural for this particular example.

Comment: Please also show the classes. And what type of LINQ you're working with (Entity Framework?) + version.

Comment: Grouping on both Name and TypeId lets me access both data in the select: ```group new { a,rp } by new { a.Name, rp.TypeId}
into arpg```  and arpg.Count() then gives me the numbers (but split on TypeId, of course). Maybe I can then group a second time, now only on Name, and now call sum()...

Comment: I'm working in Visual Studio 2013 & .Net 4.6 and not knowingly using any framework.

Comment: While it as a LINQ learning experience would be nice to know how to get this SQL into working LINQ code, in my application I made a view instead.

Comment: But then there can't be such a thing as "not knowingly using any framework". Each LINQ to a SQL backend has its own idiosyncrasies so if we are to help you we do need to know about the data access library and what the class model looks like.

Comment: While there can't be "not using any framework" there sure can be "not knowingly using any framework" - I'm thrown into woking with an existing system and wanted to start using LINQ as a "learning experience" so I will be able to maintain existing code, but how do I find out what framework is used? VS 2013, SQL Server 2008 R2 and .Net 4.6 framework are the entities known to me at this site...

Comment: How to find out? Start looking where `POAs` etc. come from. There's probably a class inheriting from `DataContext` (LINQ-to-SQL) or `DbContext` (Entity Framework), probably having all entity classes of the application in the same folder. If so, the key questions are: which navigation properties do you have in the involved entity classes? And if EF, which EF version? If none of the above, sooner or later you'll *have* to find out how the application interacts with the database.

Comment: It's LINQ-to-SQL.